# Stripping OIDs from tables in preparation for pg_upgrade

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database in RDS, file size approaching 1TB.  We started in 2005, using ruby/activerecord/rails, and along the way have upgraded to PG 9.6

Rails migrations create tables using `CREATE TABLE`, never specified whether to include OIDs or not, but never used them.  So some of our oldest (and largest) tables have OIDs.  At some point postgres stopped defaulting to creating tables with OIDs, so tables created more recently don't have this issue.

We're looking to do an upgrade 9.6 -> 12, ideally using `pg_upgrade`.  This fails complaining about tables having OIDs.

We can do `ALTER TABLE :table_name: SET WITHOUT OIDS` but for our larger tables that takes several hours, locking the table, effectively taking down the database.  We would prefer to avoid the downtime if possible.

Is it expected that an `ALTER TABLE :table_name: SET WITHOUT OIDS` should rewrite all the rows of a table?

Is there a way to avoid this rewriting?  (Ordinary columns can be dropped without rewriting all the rows, for example.)

I tried on a toy database mucking with the metadata tables:

```
UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_class SET relhasoids = 'f' WHERE oid = (
  SELECT c.oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
    JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
   WHERE n.nspname = 'public' AND c.relname = 'name_of_table'
);
```

It executed quickly and a cursory examination of the data didn't show any corruption.

But, this doesn't seem to be a documented approach.

Is this a terrible idea? Are there other approaches that don't require rewriting whole tables?

Answer (score 2):

That `UPDATE` *might* work, but I am not certain, and I wouldn't want to do that with data I value.  You don't have the option anyway, since you cannot get superuser access in a hosted database.

I can think of a safe, but more painful method:

1. Briefly suspend data modification activity on the table.
2. Create a trigger that records all data modification activity in another table.
3. Create a new table that looks like the old one, and start an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` that copies the data.

Now normal operation can be resumed.

Once the copy is done, replay the recorded changes. Then

1. Start a transaction.
2. `LOCK` the original table.
3. Replay all the changes that happened since the last replay (should be few).
4. `DROP` the original table.
5. Rename the copy to the original table name.

Foreign keys will require extra attention.

Comment: Important point:
> cannot get superuser access in a hosted database

Looks like we'll need to deal with the downtime.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your terabyte table is partitioned, you can probably do the ALTER TABLE SET WITHOUT OIDs on each partition, one at a time, which should lock it for a shorter amount of time... but is it partitioned?

A potential solution:

Postgres 10 and 11 support CREATE TABLE WITH OIDS, so you should be able to upgrade to one of these versions with pg_upgrade, even though your huge table has OIDs.

If this works, well the good thing is you have upgraded to a newer version, so you can stop there... but the new version also supports logical replication.

So, get a new server... Maybe your HDDs are old, or you would like to upgrade to SSDs? That's the occasion! So, install postgres 12 on the new server, and setup logical replication between the old server and the new. Make sure all tables are created without OIDs on the new server.

It would also be the right moment to decide about partitioning your huge table, in case you need to delete lots of old rows from it someday.

Logical replication is not binary replication, so the fact the tables use a different format isn't a problem. It will take a while to copy the whole database, but the nice thing is all the changes done to the master database while it runs are automatically replicated.

Once it has replicated, then if you chose to not create all the indexes on the empty tables (replication needs just the primary key) you can create all the indexes now. It will lock the tables on the replica, but then once it's finished it will catch up (make sure the master server keeps enough WAL to allow it to catch up).

You can also play with the new server, check everything runs fine.

Then do a failover to the new server.

After this you can setup replication the other way around, and use the old server as a hot standby backup, which is nice to have if you don't like unscheduled downtime.